# R lattice label arrows

Tags: r, text, layer, lattice

I am trying to label arrows in a plot similar to the below. I would prefer to be able to move them about where I like, as in my actual plot man of the arrows will be extended. Is there a way to label arrows in panel.arrows or other panels?

```
require(latticeExtra)
x<- 1:19
y<- 19:1
zeros <- (1:19)*0
plt <- xyplot(x~y)
plt <- plt + layer(panel.arrows(zeros,zeros,x,y,length=.1,col=1:19))
plt
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by label? You need to give more detail and a better example.

Comment: As in, if I have some vector of variable names for the arrows, how do I either create a legend for the arrows or put their names next to the arrows on the plot.

Comment: Look at `text` or `panel.text`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 plt <- plt+layer(panel.text(x=x+0.5, y=y, letters[1:19]) )
 png("labels.png")
 print(plt)
 dev.off()
```

[image]